# What is the shortest way to construct provability quantifier?

Tags: number-theory, logic

I've been trying to reproduce the proof of Gödel's incompletness theorem on my own for a seminar I attend. One of the nontrivial steps is to formulate the provability quantifier $\square p$ - as, of course, it doesn't appear naturally in first order logic.

I assume that Gödel coding of sentences $\Phi_n$ has already been established. We also have a constant $\alpha$ such that $\Phi_n$ is an axiom iff $\Phi_\alpha (n)$ holds. Other than that, I can only use first-order logic and primitive notions of Peano arithmetic: so, for instance, I have to write $\exists_m n+m=k$ instead of $n \leq k$.

My attempt at defining $\square p$ is as follows:

$\exists_{m_1}\forall_{m_2}\bigl(\forall_{m_3}(\Phi_\alpha (m_3) \land \exists_{m_4} m_3+m_4=m_1)\implies (\Phi_{m_2} \implies \Phi_{m_3})\bigr) \implies (\Phi_{m_2} \implies p)$

It seems solid enough, but it's still kinda long - so much that it doesn't fit in one line if preceeded by "$\square p :=$". So, is there some shorter definition I'm missing? Or is it as good as possible within my assumptions?

I would appreciate potential shorter formulations being posted without commentary, so that I may try to understand them by myself.

(The work isn't graded, it's more of a fun side project - the definition I came up with during the seminar was monstrously long and we've been curious if one can do better)

Comment: Just a quick comment: it is perfectly fine to introduce abbreviations of notation to make your final formula better readable. So for example, in this case you could *define* $n \leq k$ to mean $\exists m(n+m = k)$. As long as you are clear about your definitions, this will probably lead to a better readable formula.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I know it's true in general, it's just a convention we've agreed upon to make the task more fun

Comment: use : \tiny ? as I did with a 155 digit number earlier today ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I hate how you are technically right with a burning passion

Comment: @Michal you are not the first ...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws is probably not that useful compared with quantifier elimination.